# Use a string to access an Array

Tags: android, arrays, string

I am trying to get values from a string array defined in strings.xml by using a string variable.

For instance, I have two string arrays in strings.xml called "a_test_arrays" and "b_test_arrays"

In my code, I based on a random selection a string could be saved as either "a_test" or "b_test"

```
String test;
//Randomly determine value of test. test = "a_test" or test = "b_test"

String[] test_array;
//get the selected array and store it's contents in test_array
//test_array = test + "_arrays";
```

I've been trying to use resource identifiers, but I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id of an array by name using [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String test = "a_test";
Resources res = getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier(test + "_arrays", "array", "my.package.name");
String[] test_array = res.getStringArray(resId);
```

Note you can use this for any type of resource, whether it's drawable, string, etc. Just make sure you change the second parameter from "array" to the appropriate type.

Comment: Doh! I had "string" instead of "array". simple mistakes = disastrous consequences. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done:

```
String[] test_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_test);
```

Hope this helps